# QAOA Optimization

Tags: programming, qaoa

I want to use historical data for 5 stocks from YahooFinance and then calculate mean vector and covariance matrice, so I can optimize them with QAOA. Anyone know what is wrong with this code:
[image]

Comment: Which language/SDK are you using?

Comment: @Mauricio Python/Qiskit

Answer (score 0):

I overcome the problem with this code:
[image]

It might be helpfull for someone.